# $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}x(t)=0$ in a kind linear ODE in these conditions but I think I didn't need one of the conditions of the exercise to prove it

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

The exercise is: Let $a,b:\Bbb R \to\Bbb R $ be continuous functions and $M\in \Bbb R, M>0,$ such that $a(t)\ge M$ for all $t\in\Bbb R$ and $b(t)\ge \frac{1}{t^{100}}$ for all $t\ge 1$ and $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty}b(t)=0$. Proof that all the solutions of $x'(t)=-a(t)x(t)+b(t)$ verify $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}x(t)=0$.

This is what I did:

The solutions of the ODE are  $$ x_{_C}(t)=e^{-\int a(t)dt}\int (e^{\int a(t)dt}b(t))dt+Ce^{-\int a(t)dt}, C\in \Bbb R$$
First, I proved that given $t_0\in \Bbb R$, then $\lim\limits_{t\to \infty} e^{-\int_{t_0}^t a(s)ds}=0$. I shall explain if someone asks me.

Using $\lim\limits_{s \to \infty}b(s)=0$, given $\varepsilon>0$ exists $s_0$ such that $s>s_0 \implies |b(s)|<M\varepsilon$, so

$|\int_{t_0}^t (e^{\int_{t_0}^s a(r)dr}b(s))ds|=_{t>s_0}\le M\varepsilon |\int_{t_0}^t (e^{\int_{t_0}^s a(r)dr})ds|=$
$M\varepsilon|(\frac{1}{a(s)}e^{\int_{t_0}^s a(r)dr}]_{t_0}^t|\le \varepsilon|e^{\int_{t_0}^t a(s)ds}-1|$,

Multiplying by $|e^{-\int_{t_0}^t a(s)ds}|$ in the inequality:

$|e^{-\int_{t_0}^t a(s)ds}\int_{t_0}^t (e^{\int_{t_0}^s a(r)dr}b(s))ds|\le \varepsilon|1-e^{-\int_{t_0}^t a(s)ds}|<\varepsilon$.

With these we can say that $\lim\limits_{t\to \infty}x_c(t)=0$, for all $C\in \Bbb R$.

You can see that $b(t)\ge \frac{1}{t^{100}}$ wasn't needed if I made it well. Is this reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would define the general solution with limits of integration since that's what you use later:
$$ x_{C}(t)=e^{-\int_{t_0}^t a(t')dt'}\int_{t_1}^t e^{\int_{t_0}^{t''}a(t')dt'}b(t'')dt''+Ce^{-\int_{t_0}^t a(t')dt'}, C\in \Bbb R.$$

When you bound your integral with $M\epsilon$ to get rid of the $b(t)$, it's not correct because the inequality $b(t)<M\epsilon$ must be satisfied on the whole interval of integration.

I would do it like that: if the integral
$$
\int_{t_1}^\infty e^{\int_{t_0}^{t''}a(t')dt'}b(t'')dt''
$$
exists, then you are done. I believe I have to use the condition $b(t)>\frac{1}{t^{100}}$ to claim that $b(t)$ is positive (at least starting at $t=1$) and thus, if the integral above does not exists, it diverges to $\infty$. If the integral diverges, then use L'Hopital rule on
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} e^{-\int_{t_0}^t a(t')dt'}\int_{t_1}^t e^{\int_{t_0}^{t''}a(t')dt'}b(t'')dt''=
\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\int_{t_1}^t (e^{\int_{t_0}^{t''}a(t')dt'}b(t''))dt''}{e^{\int_{t_0}^t a(t')dt'}}=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\frac{b(t)}{a(t)}=0,
$$
where the next to last inequality was obtained by using L'Hopital rule and differentiating the top and bottom.